Movie about a lady telling a story about rabbits
There is a specific Movie/Series that I can vaugely recall but I cannot figure out the name of it. What I remember is:

It starts out with a middle-aged (british?) lady coming home after it starts raining and makes a cup of tea.
She has a pet rabbit at the very least and begins telling a story, where the film changes from live action to animated.
I believe she was either a painter or writer as the transition between her live action and the animated part about the rabbits was being read from a piece of paper that reminds me of stationary from a letter.
The movie/TV Series, I would assume, is early 90's or late 80's and was on VHS in America.

I know the intro with the lady is very short, probably only 5 minutes long, but I recall it being very serene and wonderful in its peacefulness. 
I believe the majority of the film after her part is about rabbits getting into trouble or something. I would like to say it was peter cottontail, but that doesn't seem right.
EDIT: After thinking about it some more, I believe that this might have been a TV series, as I don't recall it being very long. Unfortunately I can only remember this one episode/film.

That sounds like animated movie Watership Down.  The rabbits get in a lot of trouble and it there's even animated tv show. Tv series is much more light-hearted. 
Edit: How about  Song of the South?  It has rabbits in it and is as light-hearted as they come and is not that famous part of disney canon.
Edit2: Found it, I think! The world of Peter Rabbit and Friends!
Check it out here:




It is definitely not that movie. This movie had more of a light-hearted feeling to it.

Ok, I'll edit my answer. Although the tv series is more lighthearted than the movie.

It was not Song of the South either, I will update my question to include some more facts I remembered

Updated my answer again.

There it is! Thank you so much! Loved this intro and am so glad you were able to find it.
